# Reinitialize an Angular.js controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

if you have a controller to manipulate $scope variables in Angular.js, is there an idiomatic way to:

- reset the controller's $scope, and
- restart controller initialization?

For complex controllers it would be very convenient not to have to reset every variable to it's initial value, especially if what you really want is a simple reinitialization of the controller and the scope. Navigating to the same URL again via `$location.path()` doesn't help, though.

Edit: Suppose I can't use any `$window.location` hack because this would violate the CSP in Chrome Packaged Apps.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just after asking, I finally found one way to solve this using [`$route.reload()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route#reload).

```
myapp.Controller('SampleController', function($location, $route) {

  $scope.navTo = function(url) {
    if ($location.path() === url) {
      $route.reload();
    } else {
      $location.path(url);
    }
  }

});
```

I'm still thinking, that there must be some more elegant solution, but this definitely works for me.

Comment: I don't agree, I think this is a perfectly elegant solution. In a sense, you're reloading the page, so $route.reload() makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @popovitsj: While it's great to know that this doesn't have to be considered bad practice, I'm still not really convinced. While you're definitely right that there's some appeal to this solution because semantically `$route.reload()` is similiar to reloading the page, it still produces a lot of overhead. This might be ignorable in a lot of specific use cases (it definitly was in mine at that time), but it would still be nice to have an equally clean method that avoids creating this overhead.

Comment: Can we move the contents of oninit in a private method (say it 'init') and call it from oninit and finally use the same private method to reset the controller as many times as we want?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using angular-ui-router then you should do it in this way:

```
myapp.Controller('SampleController', function($state) {

    $scope.navigate = function (stateName) {
        if ($state.is(stateName)) {
            $state.reload();
        } else {
            $state.go(stateName);
        }
    }
});
```