# Reload all Controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on tabs, every tab here points to the same `<div>`

```
<div id="tabs" ng-controller="tabsController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tab in tabsList">
            <a href="#tabs-1" ng-click="selectTab(tab)">{{tab.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1" ng-controller="someController">
        <div ng-controller="childOfSomeController">
        </div>
```

On Selection of every tab, i want all the controllers to reload again, Is it possible in angularjs?

Comment: What do you mean by "reload"? As in, clear the scope?

Comment: Why would you possibly want that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413760/reinitialize-an-angular-js-controller)

Comment: create a new controller for tab & then put that controller inside ng-repeat

Comment: On Selection of tab i am adding few properties to "tabsController" scope, using those properties, i need to get the data in "someController" and its children.

Comment: Use ng-switch to switch between tabs - this will run each 'switch' in a new scope and execute all controllers within the tab when switched.