# Deleting angular controller instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-controller

For quick reading, the problem is simplified under "The problem", and for further information keep going down for background and notes before answering. Thank you!

### The problem

I want to delete the instance of a controller when refreshing the page or when moving to a different view and then returning to the same view through the navigator (`nav.html`). In fact, every time view `X.html` is visited, I want the program to check if `X-controller.js` exists, and if it does delete it before making a new instance.

How far am I going here, is it a 2 line solution I failed to find online or am I looking at hours of coding to make this work?

### Background

My project uses the `$routeProvider` service, not the the `ng-controller` directive. Once the app launches there are constantly two views, one on the top where you can navigate back and forth through the controllers "Home - Contact - Support" (logically, `nav.html`), and one on the bottom which is the "Home" or "Contact" and so on.

I haven't had any problems with this arrangement until the code begun making massive calculations. The same instance of the controller is updated with more data than it should, calculates for previous data that was discarded, and so on. I've read online about deleting the controller but as far as I know it's not that easy.

**Notes before answering the question:**

- If the second option of 'hours of coding' is the solution I'm not expecting anyone to do this for me, but references to articles or code for that would be appreciated because I haven't found anything useful on my own.
- If there is an easier solution that applies only when `ng-controller` is used and not `$routeProvider` then it's not an option for me. There are over 20 views and many sections of code which triggers redirection to a different view with a different controller using event listeners. I'm not currently planning on changing `$routeProvider` to `ng-controller`.
- If the solution doesn't actually delete the previous instance, rather clears the $scope and javascript variables then that could work for me as well.
- I haven't included code because this question is not about a bug or error, if for some reason code snippets of the `$routeProvider` configuration or one view and controller is needed let me know and I'll include that code with the classified sections replaced with similar dummy code.

**Clarification Edit**

I'll illustrate with an example. Assume `X.html` is a view controlled by `XCtrl.js`. `$scope.test` is initiated in the beginning `$scope.test = 2` of that controller, and once a button in the view is clicked `$scope.test` becomes 3. Also, the X view displays `$scope.test` all the time. So I moved to that view, clicked the button, and saw that 3 is displayed on the screen. Then I moved to "Home" through the navigator, then back to "X", and 3 is still displayed. But what I want is 2 to be displayed, and not 3. I want everything to be renewed in that controller.

**Solution**

Eventually I used a different technique to solve this. All the data saved in the local storage was affecting the $scope variables (there were too many variables to track that I didn't notice this). To solve the issue I cleared the local storage key `localStorageService.set('keyUsed', []);` once the view controlled by controller X is visited. Assume an init function, so the line of code clearing the local storage was placed in the top of that function.

I'm still marking the correct solution from the answers below for the problem I initially thought I had.

Comment: what do you mean by deleting instance of a controller? it's a function that gets executed.

Comment: @Maximus When I'm in X.html and I have a div that displays $scope.var = 2, change $scope.var to 3 with a button and move to Y.html through the navigator. Then I move back to X.html, I can see 3 displayed by $scope.var instead of 2, and I want the changes to be discarded. I want the entire controller to be "new".

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17414616/2545680)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Always have a '.' in your ng-models!
>
> -- Miško Hevery (father of AngularJS)

Most likely you have an issue with `$scope.test` and not with controller itself. If your template `x.html` refers the value of `test` as `{{test}}` (without any prefix) then most probably you are referring the `test` of the wrong scope. It usually happens due to prototypical chain of scopes that extend one another and fallback to prototype property value. In this case, choose something unique for `XCtrl` controller and put all your state inside this controller to that namespace. For example, use `x` as namespace

```
$scope.x = {};
$scope.x.test = 2;
```

instead of just

```
$scope.test = 2;
```

Then in `x.html` refer the value as

```
{{x.test}}
```

This is one of the Angular best practices.

Another best practice, that may solve your issue, is actually not using `$scope` at all, but use controller instance itself for storing state in junction with `controllerAs` syntax:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.min.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route.min.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-view>

  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/x', {
        controller: 'xCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'x',
        templateUrl: 'x.html'
      })
      .when('/y', {
        controller: 'yCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'y',
        templateUrl: 'y.html'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/x'
      })
  }])
  .controller('xCtrl', [function() {
    var x = this;
    x.test = 2;
    x.doSomething = function() {
      x.test ++;
    };
  }])
  .controller('yCtrl', [function() {
    var y = this;
    y.hello = 'Hello';
  }])
```

**x.html**

```
<h1>X.html</h1>
<p>test = {{x.test}}</p>
<button ng-click="x.doSomething()">+1</button>
<a href="#/y">Link to Y</a>
```

**y.html**

```
<h1>Y.html</h1>
<p>{{y.hello}}</p>
<a href="#/x">Link to X</a>
```

**Live Demo:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/EpUn94uWMliTaG5mvPxv?p=preview

**Links:**

- To understand the issue with not having a '.' in your model, see [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m) video by Miško Hevery.
- To better understand `controllerAs` approach, you can read [this](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) post by Todd Motto.

Comment: Thank you for the the elaborated solution Vadim, but unfortunately the $scope variables in my code were affected by the local storage which saved data from previous visits to that view, and not by the structure of the project. It was my fault I didn't notice that one line of code loading data from the local storage.